# ToolingConnection's query method throwing com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to load class: com.sforce.soap.tooling.InvalidSObjectFault

Tags: soap-api, java, tooling-api

I'm using Salesforce Tooling API in Java code and I am able to use create method of ToolingConnection. 
Bellow code is creating an apex class successfully.

I'm getting exception when using query method of ToolingConnection.

 Any help really appreciated. Please find my java method bellow.

```
public void demoTooling(ToolingConnection toolingConnection ) {
try {
    // Bellow code is running as expected. Apex class created successfully.
    String classBody = "public class Messages {\n"
                   + "public string SayHello() {\n"
                   + " return 'Hello';\n" + "}\n"
                   + "}";
    ApexClass apexClass = new ApexClass();
    apexClass.setBody(classBody);
    ApexClass[] classes = { apexClass };
    SaveResult[] saveResults = toolingConnection.create(classes);

    // Bellow code is throwing exception
     String soql = "Select Id From CustomObject Limit 1";
     QueryResult queryResult = toolingConnection.query(soql);
     System.out.print("**"+ queryResult);
} catch (Exception ce) {
    ce.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

**Exception after executing toolingConnection.query** :

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to parse detail:  START_TAG seen ...<detail><sf:InvalidSObjectFault xsi:type="sf:InvalidSObjectFault">... @1:436 due to: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to load class: com.sforce.soap.tooling.InvalidSObjectFault
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.parseDetail(SoapConnection.java:246)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:210)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:156)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:99)
    at com.sforce.soap.tooling.ToolingConnection.query(ToolingConnection.java:650)
    at controller.ToolingController.describe(ToolingController.java:44)
    at controller.ToolingController.main(ToolingController.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.soap.tooling.InvalidSObjectFault
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.load(TypeMapper.java:763)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.getJavaType(TypeMapper.java:740)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:623)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:556)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.parseDetail(SoapConnection.java:236)
```

Comment: What version of Java and Tooling API are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.8 and Tooling API 24.0. Thanks Jayant for quick response

Comment: Did you mean JDK 8.1 and 42.0?

Comment: I meant JDK 8 (1.8)  and Tooling API was older 24.  <br/> But just updated Tooling API version as 40.0 and it worked. Thanks for the hint that might be due to version issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking around this issue looks like more to be API/Java version. If you see the excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) at SOAP API, it mentions as:

> Salesforce does not guarantee that an application written against one SOAP API version will work with future SOAP API versions: Changes in method signatures and data representations are often required as we continue to enhance SOAP API. However, we strive to keep SOAP API consistent from version to version with minimal if any changes required to port applications to newer SOAP API versions.

In this scenario, the Tooling API was 24.0 and upgrading it to 40.0 worked. Though Salesforce strives for backward compatibility, but its always recommended you upgrade your application's connectors to latest Salesforce API versions with every release (or at least test and validate for correctness).

Comment: Awesome  @Jayant Das 
This version update also saved me from other issue like picklist data type.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was using version API version 24 and above issue occurred.
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/24.0/

I have changed it to 40.0 and now query method working well.
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/40.0/

Thanks @Jayant Das for quick hint about version discussion in comment :)

Comment: Typical etiquette around these parts is to reply in the comments asking the helpful poster to put their advice in an answer, which you can then upvote and accept.

Comment: Taking a cue from @AdrianLarson, I have provided some details around this as an answer.